# Visual Studio 2013 MVC - jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I have just begun to create an application in Visual Studio 2013 using MVC. I am trying to use jquery datapicker. I want it to show a datepicker where ever there is a DateTime field. I am creating my controllers using scaffolding (templates).

1. I have imported the JQuery UI (combined Library).
2. In the BundleConfig.css I added "~/Content/themes/base/all.css" to the bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include
3. Additionally added a new bundle --

   ```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
          "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js));
   ```
4. In the _Layout.cshtml I added 2 new Scripts.Render

   ```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
   @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/AQB_MON.js")
   ```
5. I created my AQB_MON.js with the following

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".input[type='datetime']").each(function(){
       $(this).datepicker();
      });
   })
   ```

All seems to have no affect on any datetime field. Is this due to using scaffolding to create my Controllers/Views? As I was trying to use ToShortDateString() when displaying my datetime fields and came across an issue due to having scaffolding build them.

Comment: Have you loaded _jquery.js_? Are there any script errors in the debug console? Do your input controls have the class `input` -- that's what your selector is searching for.

Comment: As far as I know I have loaded jquery.js. I am not receiving any errors of any kind in the debug console. I am not sure about the input class. I am new to this and not sure where to look to find out.

Comment: The selector `.input` means you have added the class "input" to an input element `<input class="input" ...>`. If this is not the case then your selector is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use htmlhelper to display the datetime picker. 
Read more about html helper.

Comment: I believe I am using html helper to dispay the datetime picker - @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate. Instead of attaching the datepicker widget to one specific element, I am trying to attach the widget to any input element with a type attribute of datetime.